# Rails Mass 301 redirect - will it cause routes.rb issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, routes

I have a large set of URLs that I need to redirect (over 600), which are all unique. They're all named URLs (i.e. example.com/this-shoe-name and example.com/that-blue-product), so I can't use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402977/mass-301-redirects-in-rails-3) to semi-dynamically do this, and they also don't redirect to anything similar (i.e. www.example.com/this-shoe-name redirects to newexample.com/catalog/shoes vs. newexample.com/this-shoe-name).

I guess I'm fine writing 600 redirect rules (though I'd rather avoid it), but that seems to me like it's going to make the routes.rb file rather unwieldy.

Short of writing 600 rules in routes.rb, is there a best practice way to do this? Is having 600 rules in the routes.rb going to make my app slow/break things?

Comment: Can you offer more explicit redirects as well as a reasonable explanation as to why this needs to occur? I am struggling to understand why you would need this breadth of redirection and also why a RESTful instance would instead redirect to an index page *"www.example.com/this-shoe-name redirects to newexample.com/catalog/shoes"*

Comment: @engineersmnky The short answer is that I'm streamlining an client's legacy system and they had really bad naming conventions. What I'm doing it redoing the naming conventions, but still redirecting users that might visit the old URL (highly unlikely, but what am I going to do, tell them no? Maybe I should...). So if someone visits www.example.com/this-shoe-name I can still get them to the catalog. Not to mention that specific shoe is discontinued, and I'd rather keep people away from the 404 page of doom. If possible.

Comment: Will there be anything left of "example.com" when you are done? If not then why not just redirect "example.com" to "newexample.com" all together or just change the DNS. Then you could have a catch all route at the bottom of "newexample.com"? Just an idea becuase what you are proposing will be extremely tedious to manage not to mention error prone.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, that sounds about right - tedious and error prone has been the name of this project. Largely trying to pacify the client here, which is the only reason I'm even considering this....that said, at the end of the day this is an SEO issue. They want their old links to bring their former SEO clout to the new links. Which means (I believe) that a catch all redirect would eliminate most of the point of setting up the redirects to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will slow routing processing down, but I doubt it. As long as you put them at the end, do you really care?  Like you I don't like the messiness it causes.

An alternative would be to create a catch all route or rescue the 404 and then look up the URL in a "old urls" table and if a match is found redirect to the new url.

You might even be able to tie that "old url" into your Product or Category model as an attribute.  Then search that and if found redirect to the correct url for that model. I've done that in the past with pretty good success.  Bonus is that you can expose it in an admin tool and make the client enter them all in :-)

Comment: I don't care if it slows down _those_ particular routes, but I don't want the root url to suffer (for example), because the routes.rb file is so heavy. I agree with you: I doubt it, but I just don't know.

I don't even know how to being on the 404 workaround you're suggesting, so perhaps I'll settle for messy and annoying for now.

Your last solution sounds like my favorite though :) Let the client do it!

Comment: Routes are a first match first use deal so should be fine.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks for the confirmation!